# How to display events by order wise in FullCalendar timelineYear view

Tags: fullcalendar

[image]

In this image, i wanted to display **june** events vertically below to the **May** month events under june month, I had used **eventOrder** value for may as 1 and for june as 2.

Please help!!

Expected Result:

[image: timelineYear]

Comment: Is that a picture of your old calendar, or from your fullCalendar attempt? I don't think fullCalendar provides any views like this, unless perhaps it's the Timeline view, but even then I don't think so. Also which version of fullCalendar are you using? And https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder says it _Determines the ordering events within the **same day**_ ...so clearly it's not going to do anything about different months, I don't know why you tried that.

Comment: Overall your question is a little unclear, lacking clarity, detail and relevant code. Please review the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better understanding of how to ask a clear, answerable question - thanks.

Comment: @ADyson
First of all Thank you for responding.
I had used fullcalendar v5 with angular 10 and yes i used timelineYear.
we had that requirement to display different month events vertically one below another in their respective columns.


I would prefer a solution rather suggesting on asking a answerable question. 
Thanks you sir!!

Comment: Like I said above I don't think this is possible with fullCalendar, except perhaps if you make your own completely custom view, but that is a very big job, even if you start by cloning an existing one

Comment: @ADyson
thankyou again,

I had provided an answer. Please upvote if it seems good and any code improvement suggestion a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If somebody had requirement on **timelineYear** like below.
[timelineYear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a0Mn.png)

Use a method named **eventsSet** which is passed to **[options]** of **`<full-calendar>`**.

Sample script goes here:

```
eventsSet:  (info) => {

    let prevHeight = 0, prevTop = 0, setTop = 0;
    let allEvents;
    setTimeout(() => {
      allEvents = document.getElementsByClassName("fc-timeline-event-harness");
      if(allEvents.length > 0) {
        for (let item of allEvents) {
            prevHeight = item.offsetHeight;
            setTop = prevTop + prevHeight;
            item.style.top = prevTop + 'px';
            prevTop = setTop;
         }
      }
    }, 100);
  }
```